# jQuery Mobile persisten fixed header tab bar with page transition

Tags: jquery-mobile, tabbar, ibm-mobilefirst

i'm developing a simple three tabs app for Android and iPhone, using IBM Worklight as framework. Every tab links to a div with data-role="page", as jQuery Mobile specifications.

If I implement the jquery fixed persistent tabbar like is explained there (http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/toolbars/footer-persist-a.html), i'm encountering some flickering on the tab item in page transition (with any transiction effect).
If I set the default transition to "none", I could resolve this problem, but I lost the transiction native-like effect.

This behavior appears only if i test the App with a real android device (Xperia Neo, GS2).

If i navigate trough the pages of http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/ with my smartphone, especially here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/toolbars/footer-persist-d.html i can't see the strange behavior, but the footer won't be persistent trough the pages, it just re-render like the whole content and this is worse (this happen with the stock browser or Dolphin, instead looks very well by using Chrome).

Is there a way to improve this effect or there is another way to implement fixed persistent tab bar?

I used as reference the default Android Contacts App.

Comment: ever find a fix for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to poor performance of the WebView of the Android environment in rendering 3d transition.
Solved by removing the transition effect with:

`$.mobile.defaultPageTransition = "none";`

Something else that could help is putting these attributes in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="false"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="false" />
 <application
        android:debuggable="false"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you're getting this flicker because you're navigating between pages using `rel="external"`. Try to pass from one page to the other without ajax and you'll see that flickering will dissapear

Comment: No no, i have three div with data-role="page" in a single HTML page.